# Get LUN paths for esxi host using powercli

Tags: powershell

I am looking to get the path details

[image]

I am trying the below code to do that but getting some errors

```
$vkcpw = Get-Content E:\Encrypted_Password\vkcpw.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content E:\Encrypted_Password\V-center_aes.key)
$vcentercredential   = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("",$vkcpw)
Connect-VIServer -server 192.168.1.3 -Credential $vcentercredential

function Get-LUNPathState {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position = 0,HelpMessage = 'ESXi Host',ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [Alias('Name')]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        $VMhosts
    )

    $ReportLunPathState = @()
    $i = 0

    try
    {
        ForEach ($VMHost in $VMhosts) {
            $i++
            $VMHostDatastores = Get-Datastore
            $VMHostScsiLuns = $VMHost | Get-ScsiLun -LunType disk


            ForEach ($VMHostScsiLun in $VMHostScsiLuns) {
                $VMHostScsiLunPaths = $VMHostScsiLun | Get-ScsiLunPath
                $ReportLunPathState += ($VMHostScsiLunPaths | Measure-Object) | Select-Object `
                -Property @{N = 'Hostname'; E = {$VMHost.Name}}, `
                @{N = 'Datastore'; E = {$VMHostDatastores | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.extensiondata.info.vmfs.extent | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.diskname}) -contains $VMHostScsiLun.CanonicalName}| Select-Object -ExpandProperty name}}, `
                @{N = 'CanonicalName'; E = {$VMHostScsiLun.CanonicalName}}, `
                @{N = '# of Paths'; E = {$_.Count}}, `
                @{N = 'Path State'; E = {$VMHostScsiLunPaths.State}}
            }
        }
    
}

Get-LUNPathState -VMhosts 'gen35'
```

I am getting error

```
Get-ScsiLun     Get-ScsiLun does not accept string input through pipeline. The string 'gen35' was ignored.
```

Please let me know what is the issue here. or am I doing wrong to get the below data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all - don't attempt to pipe input to `Get-ScsiLun`, it won't be able to bind it to the correct parameter.

Change this line:

```
$VMHostScsiLuns = $VMHost | Get-ScsiLun -LunType disk
```

to:

```
$VMHostScsiLuns = Get-ScsiLun -VMHost $VMHost -LunType disk
```

Comment: Thanks @MathiasRJessen. The error is gone but the output is coming number of paths for all as 0